Vue ElementPlus Table rendered wrong

<template>
    <div class="flex flex-wrap gap-4 items-center">
        <el-button @click="reload" title="Refresh" type="info">
            <el-icon>
                <Refresh />
            </el-icon>
        </el-button>
    </div>
    <el-table v-loading="loading" :data="stats">
        <el-table-column prop="cat_code" label="category" width="200" />
        <el-table-column prop="type_code" label="type" width="200" />
        <el-table-column prop="iso_code" label="lang" width="100" />
        <el-table-column prop="missing" label="missing" width="100" />
        <el-table-column prop="obsolete" label="obsolete" width="100" />
        <el-table-column prop="good" label="good" width="100" />
    </el-table>
</template>

Looks like this:

The headers are aligned to left, the data grid is aligned to the center.
Why?
I don't have any custom CSS, just the default dark mode css for Element-Plus

Finally, I figured out that I need to have at least one column without width specified. Then the data table will occupy all available space, and cells will be aligned with the column headers.
Somehow I still feel that this is not a real solution. But it works.
